# Some Ashot strategies have "simulator" word, what's the difference between them?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, ashot

I've been working on Ashot library and Browserstack API for Selenium to take screenshots of the devices. And going through the shooting strategies I have noticed that there is a "simulator" strategy for some of the strategies available.

There's very little documentation for the ashot library :/

```
public static ShootingStrategy iPad2WithIOS8() {
    VariableCutStrategy cutStrategy = new VariableCutStrategy(41, 65, 960);
    return viewportNonRetina(500, cutStrategy);
}

public static ShootingStrategy iPad2WithIOS8Simulator() {
    VariableCutStrategy cutStrategy = new VariableCutStrategy(41, 65, 1250);
    return viewportNonRetina(500, cutStrategy);
}

public static ShootingStrategy iPad2WithIOS8Retina() {
    VariableCutStrategy cutStrategy = new VariableCutStrategy(41, 65, 960);
    return viewportRetina(500, cutStrategy, 2.0F);
}

public static ShootingStrategy iPad2WithIOS8RetinaSimulator() {
    VariableCutStrategy cutStrategy = new VariableCutStrategy(41, 65, 1250);
    return viewportRetina(500, cutStrategy, 2.0F);
```

There is a Simulator version for each one of those. Does someone know what's the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because one of them works for simulation and others for real devices.